# What happened to the perfect mirror?

Tags: optics, reflection, fiber-optics

Back in 1998 an article was published in Science by JPL's Jon Dowling [claiming a method for making a perfect dielectric mirror](http://phys.lsu.edu/~jdowling/mit.html):  "Mirror on the Wall: You're Omnidirectional After All?" Jonathan P. Dowling, Science 282, (04 December 1998) 1841-1842.

This technology purportedly would do away with fibers for light tranmission, to be replaced with dielectric tubes which could transmit light unamplified for hundreds of miles and no loss around corners.

The technology seems to have gone nowhere. What happened?

Comment: You mean there is no demand? That's a question for economics, not for physics.

Comment: I may have found a technological reason why the application of this system is somewhat difficult: it seems to require a large difference in the index of refraction of the two materials used for the layers. While these material combinations seem to exist in the infrared, in the optical band the choices seem to be limited. That kind of blows some cold air over it...

Comment: The optical fibre application is being used but as @Curious One has noted only in the infrared http://edition.cnn.com/2008/HEALTH/12/19/laser.surgery/index.html

Comment: @Farcher: That's a "cool" use for it... in the most physical sense of the word.